# Same type variable in two private subclasses not recognized as same

Tags: java, generics, subclass

Doing a bit of research implementing data structures I found a problem when trying to make two subclasses with the same generic class as the parent.

I haven't found this problem before because I usually avoid doing private sub classes, although this time I wanted to do a quick test and found this.

I can make it work without having `Node<T>` as the `current` type, but `Node`, and then casting to `T`. But I'd like to know why the compiler doesn't understand it's the same `T` as in Node. It thinks `T` in Node and `T` in `LinkedStackIterator` are two different `T`s, even though `T` in node is recognized as `T` in `LinkedStack`.

```
public class LinkedStack<T> implements Iterable<T>{
    private Node<T> first = null;

    private class Node<T>{
        private T       item;
        private Node    next;
    }

    private class LinkedStackIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{
        private Node<T> current = first; //Error here

        public boolean hasNext() { return current.next == null; }
        public void     remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
        public T        next()
        {
            T item      = current.item;
            current     = current.next;
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

```
Error: incompatible types: LinkedStack<T#1>.Node<T#1> can not be converted to LinkedStack<T#1>.LinkedStackIterator<T#2> where T#1 and T#2 are type variables.
T#1 extends Object in LinkedStack
T#2 extends Object in LinkedStack.LinkedStackIterator.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to add the generic type to the second class, `LinkedStackIterator`. It will inherit the type from the outer class.

Note, that although using the same name `T`, for the type parameter, it will be a *different* parameter than the outer class. For the same reason, in the first inner class `Node`, it would be better to use a different name for the parameter, e.g. `Node<U>`, to make the difference clear.

The following code compiles fine for me (after making `LinkedStack` abstract):

```
public abstract class LinkedStack<T> implements Iterable<T>{
    private Node<T> first = null;

    private class Node<U>{
        private U       item;
        private Node<U>    next;
    }

    private class LinkedStackIterator implements Iterator<T>{
        private Node<T> current = first; //Error here

        public boolean hasNext() { return current.next == null; }
        public void     remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
        public T        next()
        {
            T item      = current.item;
            current     = current.next;
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you declare **two distinct** `T` types :

```
public class LinkedStack<T> implements Iterable<T>{
     ...
    private class LinkedStackIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{
    ...
}
```

So this statement cannot compile :

```
 private Node<T> current = first;
```

as the `first` variable refers to a different type from the `current` variable.
`first` refers the `LinkedStack`'s `T` while `current` refers the `LinkedStackIterator`'s `T`

To allow the two classes to work with the same `T` type, don't declare a second time `T` in the inner class but reuse which one declared in the outer class :

```
private class LinkedStackIterator implements Iterator<T>{
```

Answer (score 0):

*the generic type* `T` *is inherited from the* `LinkedStack<T>` *class*
so there are the 2 possible definitions of `Node`

this is the one I would prefer – note the `static`

```
private static class Node<T> {
  private T item;
  private Node<T> next;
}
```

if You need for some reasons `Node` to be non static
*(only the* `item` *must be of type* `T` *)*

```
private class Node {
  private T item;
  private Node next;
}
```